# Changing the display of the lines in an epidemiological SID model GGPLOT graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

if anyone can help that would be appreciated.

I want the graph (in the picture) to have ribbons instead of the lines it shows on the graph below like as follows.

I'm pretty sure I need to change something in the AES part but am unsure as to what:

```
ggplot(final_results_for_plotting) +
geom_line(mapping = aes(x = time, y = number, colour = compartment)) +
labs(x = "Time (days)",
y = "Number of individuals",
colour = "Model compartment")
```

Can anyone[image] point me in the right direction please?

Comment: If you want a ribbon then of course do you need a `geom_ribbon` and instead of y you have to map on the ymin and ymax aes. Additionally, from the zig-zag pattern of your lines I would guess that you have multiple obs. per point of time. Perhaps your data is in the wrong shape? For more help provide a [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that at each time point, you have a high, low and middle point. You are plotting all of these points in each line, so each line starts at the top of the range for that date, goes straight down to the bottom of the range for that date, goes back up to the middle of the range, *then* goes across to the next day and does it all over again.

Let's attempt to recreate your plot using a generated data set:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(final_results_for_plotting) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = time, y = number, colour = compartment)) +
  labs(x = "Time (days)", colour = "Model compartment")
```

[image]

With a `geom_ribbon`, you need a column of values in your data frame for the upper limit and a column for the lower limit at each time point. We can rearrange the data to do this using some tidyverse functions:

```r
final_results_for_plotting %>%
  group_by(time, compartment) %>%
  summarise(lower = min(number), 
            upper = max(number), 
            mid = median(number)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = upper, ymin = lower, fill = compartment),
              alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(aes(color = compartment, y = mid)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Number of individuals", labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1', guide = 'none') +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  labs(x = "Time (days)", colour = "Model\ncompartment") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
final_results_for_plotting <- data.frame(
  time = rep(1:60, 9),
  number = c(pnorm(1:60, 35, 7) * 2.95 * 1e5, 
             pnorm(1:60, 36, 7) * 2.8 * 1e5,
             pnorm(1:60, 35.5, 7) * 2.88 * 1e5,
             dnorm(1:60, 35, 7) * 15 * 1e5,
             dnorm(1:60, 35, 7) * 13 * 1e5,
             dnorm(1:60, 35, 7) * 14 * 1e5,
             (3.5 - pnorm(1:60, 35, 7) * 2.95) * 1e5,
             (3.5 - pnorm(1:60, 35.5, 7) * 2.8) * 1e5,
             (3.5 - pnorm(1:60, 36, 6) * 2.88) * 1e5),
  compartment = rep(c('D', 'I', 'S'), each = 180))
```